# Looking for Simple Way To Unit Test Spring-WS Endpoint Methods

Tags: spring, spring-ws

As the topic states, I am looking for a simple was to test ONLY the endpoint mapping urls for a Spring-WS service. For example, here is a sample method:

```
@Endpoint
public class ServiceClass {
private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://mysite.com/thisApp/schemas";

    @PayloadRood(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart="Method1")
    @ResponsePayload
    public ResponseObject method1(@RequestPayload RequestObject request) {
        // do something
        // return the ResponseObject
    }
}
```

All I want to do is verify that a call to http://mysite.com/thisApp/schemas{serviceName actually hits a method; I don't care (yet) whether there is a response. In other words, I need to ensure that a NoEndpointFoundException is not returned.

I know Spring-WS has mock servers and clients, but I'm not quite seeing what I'm looking for.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if [rest-assured](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/) maybe helpful for your unit test.